# Convert a v8 Object to a custom C++ object

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv, v8, node.js-addon

I'm currently developing a `nodejs` module, written in C++ and I've been looking for a way to convert a `v8::Object` to a `cv::Mat` object from `opencv`, without any luck for now.

I saw that [nan library](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) could help to convert objects, but i couldn't find how, I don't even know if it's possible to convert them in my case.

The [v8 juice](https://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/) project would meet my expectations but since it has been abandoned, I just don't know how to do this.

Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to do :

```
void
BRMatcher::run(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args)
{
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
  v8::HandleScope scope(isolate);

  if (args.Length() < 1)
  {
    isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::TypeError(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Missing parameter [Mat img].")));
    return ;
  }

  if (!args[0]->IsObject())
  {
    isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::TypeError(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Parameter [Mat img] must be an object.")));
    return ;
  }

  v8::Local<v8::Object> cvMat(args[0]->ToObject());

  Mat img = ??? // This is where I ended up...
  // ...
}
```

All the posts talking about this on StackOverflow are outdated (older versions or tools that are not working anymore...)

So my ***questions*** are: how can I convert the argument I receive in my function to a `cv::Mat` object ? To any type I want ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you should just `get` the `properties` of `v8::Object` and assign them to appropriate fields of `cv::Mat` (or any other C++ object). Sometimes you do this with constructor arguments, sometimes with setter fuctions and sometimes with plain assignment

Comment: Dont know about v8::objects but if those have some kind of data buffer for the image data you can just create a mat the size you need and just copy the image data from the v8 buffer to the mat using cv::SetData (be careful about the type of the data)

Comment: It would also be more useful if you provided you js code. What kind of object are converting from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I would recommend to look on existing openCV bindings for Node.js like [node-opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv).

If you need to bind C++ and JavaScript code, there are several libraries. As an author of one of them, [v8pp](https://github.com/pmed/v8pp), I know about several other:

- [vu8](https://github.com/tsa/vu8) (abandoned)
- [v8-juice](http://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/) (abandoned)
- Script bindng in [cpgf](https://github.com/cpgf/cpgf)
- [Embind](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html)

As I know, to convert a C++ object into v8::Object all of them use `v8::Object::SetAlignedPointerInInternalField()` function.

C++ object to `v8::Object` conversions are usually performed with mapping  of a C++ pointer to persistent handle of the V8 object in a map container.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer, was really helpful. I finally succeed to achieve this by using bindings of `node-opencv`
You explained how to convert a C++ object into v8::Object, can you explain me how to convert any v8::Object to a specific C++ object ? Is this possible when we're pretty sure about what type it's gonna be ?

Comment: The binding libraries above use something like `v8::Object::GetAlignedPointerFromInternalField()` function to get a pointer to a wrapped C++ and to cast this pointer to some known type T*

Answer (score 1):

Do have a look on the `Nodejs.org` C++ addon and `Nan` tutorials. Though both are a little misleading, they anyhow describe the canonical way. Use `Nan` over direct `V8` APIs since especially this part (was and still) is changing a lot.

With `Nan` what you're looking for is [passing wrapped objects](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/tree/master/8_passing_wrapped/nan). More precisely this [line](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/blob/master/8_passing_wrapped/nan/myobject.cc#L22) is the heart of it.

In [this fork](https://github.com/eljefedelrodeodeljefe/node-opencv/tree/feature/refactor-to-js) of [Node-OpenCV](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv), I am doing exactly that with `cv::Mat` in order to make it a first class object for JS-land. Maybe this implementation may help you.

> #### TL;DR
>
> Wrap the object with `Nan::ObjectWrap` and pass it around. Internally uses `v8::SetInternalFieldPointer();` for you. This is basically copy-paste-able.

```js
// lib/mat.js
var cv = require('./bindings')('addon');

function Mat() {

}

/**
 * returns the wrapped c++ object
 * [arguments optional]
 */
Mat.prototype.createMat = function (a) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return cv.Mat.createMat(args[0])
}
```

```c++
// src/addon.cc
// just initializes all your modules. Magic happening in mat.h and matwrap.h 
// matwrap.cc is the implementation of the wrapped object. mat.cc holds 
// JS-libarary specific methods 

#include <nan.h>
#include "opencv.h"
#include "imgproc.h"
#include "mat.h"
#include "matwrap.h"

void InitAll(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) {
   Opencv::Init(exports);
   ImgProc::Init(exports);
   Matwrap::Init();
   Mat::Init(exports);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, InitAll)
```

Important stuff here...

```c++
// src/matwrap.h
#ifndef MATWRAP_H
#define MATWRAP_H

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <nan.h>

class Matwrap : public Nan::ObjectWrap {
 public:
  static void Init();
  static v8::Local<v8::Object> NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Value> arg);
  cv::Mat Val() const { return val_; }

 private:
  Matwrap();
  ~Matwrap();

  static Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor;
  static void New(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info);
  cv::Mat val_;
};

#endif
```

...and **here** you're are wrapping it (basically that's it; follow below for consumption):

```c++
// src/matwrap.cc
#include <node.h>
#include "matwrap.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Matwrap::Matwrap() {};
Matwrap::~Matwrap() {};

Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> Matwrap::constructor;

void Matwrap::Init() {
  Nan::HandleScope scope;

  // Prepare constructor template
  v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> tpl = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(New);
  tpl->SetClassName(Nan::New("Matwrap").ToLocalChecked());
  tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

  constructor.Reset(tpl->GetFunction());
}

void Matwrap::New(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
  // wrap it...
  Matwrap* obj = new Matwrap();
  cv::Mat src;
  obj->val_ = src;
  obj->Wrap(info.This());
  // return wrapped here...
  info.GetReturnValue().Set(info.This());
}

v8::Local<v8::Object> Matwrap::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Value> arg) {
  Nan::EscapableHandleScope scope;

  // const unsigned argc = 1;
  // v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[argc] = { arg };
  v8::Local<v8::Function> cons = Nan::New<v8::Function>(constructor);
  v8::Local<v8::Object> instance = cons->NewInstance();

  return scope.Escape(instance);
}
```

> For consumption you could do stuff like this:

```js
// lib/mat.js
/**
 * Returns true if the array has no elements.
 * @param  {Object} mat - native cv::Mat
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
Mat.prototype.empty = function (mat) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return cv.Mat.empty(args[0])
}
```

```c++
// src/mat.h
// This is your API
#ifndef MAT_H
#define MAT_H

// #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <nan.h>

class Mat : public Nan::ObjectWrap {
 public:
  static void Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports);

 private:
  explicit Mat(double value = 0);
  ~Mat();

  static void New(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info);
  static void CreateMat(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info);
  static void Empty(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info);
  static void Total(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info);
  static void Type(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info);
  static Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor;
  double value_;
};
#endif
```

```c++
// src/mat.cc
#include "mat.h"
#include "matwrap.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> Mat::constructor;

Mat::Mat(double value) : value_(value) {
}

Mat::~Mat() {
}

void Mat::Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) {
  Nan::HandleScope scope;

  // Prepare constructor template
  v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> tpl = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(New);
  tpl->SetClassName(Nan::New("Mat").ToLocalChecked());
  tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

  // Prototype
  Nan::SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "createMat", CreateMat);
  Nan::SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "empty", Empty);
  Nan::SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "total", Total);
  Nan::SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "type", Type);

  constructor.Reset(tpl->GetFunction());
  exports->Set(Nan::New("Mat").ToLocalChecked(), tpl->GetFunction());
}

void Mat::New(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
  if (info.IsConstructCall()) {
    // Invoked as constructor: `new Opencv(...)`
    double value = info[0]->IsUndefined() ? 0 : info[0]->NumberValue();
    Mat* obj = new Mat(value);
    obj->Wrap(info.This());
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(info.This());
  } else {
    // Invoked as plain function `Opencv(...)`, turn into construct call.
    const int argc = 1;
    v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[argc] = { info[0] };
    v8::Local<v8::Function> cons = Nan::New<v8::Function>(constructor);
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(cons->NewInstance(argc, argv));
  }
}

void Mat::CreateMat(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {

  info.GetReturnValue().Set(Matwrap::NewInstance(info[0]));
}

void Mat::Empty(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {

  Matwrap* obj = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Matwrap>(info[0]->ToObject());
  // check through cv::Mat::empty()
  if (obj->Val().empty()) {
    // return JS bool
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::True());
  } else {
    // TODO: logically not correct
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::False());
  }
}
```